# Select line matching pattern followed by substitution using `sed`

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Here's what I'm trying to replicate:

```
$ cat << EOF | { var=$(grep 'foo=');\
 if (( $? == 0 )); then echo "$var"\
| sed -E 's/foo=(.+)/\1/'; else exit 1; fi; }
foo
foo=bar
EOF
```

> bar

Using `sed` exclusively:

```
$ cat << EOF | sed -nE '/foo=/p s/foo=(.+)/\1/'
foo
foo=bar
EOF
```

> sed: -e expression #1, char 9: extra characters after command

What is the cause of the error, and how would one fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do

```bsh
sed -n -E '/foo=/ s/foo=(.+)/\1/p' <<'END_INPUT'
foo
foo=bar
END_INPUT
```

Your command had a `p` after the initial address (the regular expression `foo=`), which turned it into a complete `sed` editing command (with the `s/...` as trailing junk that `sed` complained about) rather than an address for the `s` command.

In the command above, `/foo=/` is an address for the subsequent `s` command.  The `s` command would be applied to each line matching the regular expression `foo=`. The `-n` option to `sed` makes it avoid printing the editing buffer after each cycle, which is why we use the `p` flag with the `s` command to print the modified line.

However, you could also write that as

```bsh
sed -n '/foo=./ s/foo=//p' <<'END_INPUT'
foo
foo=bar
END_INPUT
```

which deletes the `foo=` bit on each line that has a `foo=` bit followed by something.

Or, shorter, by letting the `s` command reuse the regular expression used as the address (and then obviously assuming that we don't *require* that there is anything after `foo=`),

```bsh
sed -n '/foo=/ s///p' <<'END_INPUT'
foo
foo=bar
END_INPUT
```

Or, even shorter, by recognizing that the `s` command would not change lines that don't match the regular expression anyway,

```bsh
sed -n 's/foo=//p' <<'END_INPUT'
foo
foo=bar
END_INPUT
```

Or, without `-n`, by deleting all uninteresting lines and modifying only the ones that are interesting and relying on the default output at the end of the cycle,

```bsh
sed -e '/foo=/!d' -e 's///' <<'END_INPUT'
foo
foo=bar
END_INPUT
```